# SQLSyntax error during automatic table creation in MYSQL DB by spring jpa application

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

[image]This is my Product.java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product",schema="productcrud")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
private String desc;
private long price;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public long getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(long price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="productcrudapp"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
 name="viewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" name="ds">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productcrud"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
 name="factory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop 
  key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hiberntae.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>
                productcrudapp.model.Product
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate" 
 name="hibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" 
 name="transactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>
</bean>

 </beans>
```

This a springmvc application being hosted on Tomcat server on localhost
Here I am trying to create a Product table in productcrud schema. I have all the dependencies present in xml file and also the schema already exists in DB. And if I am trying to run this application I am getting a SQLSyntax error.
What wrong I am doing?

Comment: please post your stacktrace

Comment: If the stacktrace does not show the bad sql, try to shown it be increasing the log level on the relevant package to TRACE and adding the relevant part to the question.

Comment: Also, setting spring.jpa.show-sql=true might reveal the bad SQL

Comment: Thanks, I have added the screenshot of error. Also, where to add these statement to reveal the bad SQL

Comment: I added a try catch block where there was a add (into the DB) function. The exception is gone, but the table is not being created still